# How to completly disable the onscreen keyboard (Caribou) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: onscreen-keyboard

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.9 on a kiosk that is running a Chromium that displays a
web app. App has a custom built in on-screen keyboard. However, every time when user taps on any of the input fields, a default Gnome on-screen keyboard (Caribou or whatever it is called) pops up (despite being disabled in the Universal Access settings).

There is a workaround to disable the keyboard via Gnome Tweaks [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/) , but I can not install the Gnome Tweaks, as they are incompatible with the later versions of the shell, like the one that I'm running.

How to completly uninstall/disable this damn on-screen keyboard?! I'm totally ok with hacky solutions by this point, as I'm getting really pissed at Gnome by this point.

Comment: Frame challenge: Do you really need GNOME? If you just want to run something like Chromium as a kiosk, try [doing this](https://github.com/neoxharsh/Raspberry-Pi-App-without-desktop-environment). It should work on a device that isn't a Pi.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639934/135634)?

Comment: Thanks @cocomac - I followed your suggestion, instead of Ubuntu I installed a Raspbian Desktop (distro that is compatible with i386 x86/x64 CPUs), installed a Chromium and set it to autostart in kiosk mode and open our web app, made some small tweaks to default sleep and power configuration, and was done in 20 minutes.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution for this. Have tried Caribou blocker and it doesn't work with latest 20.04 update. It is pretty bad when you have to swtich distros to get rid of the on screen keyboard...